# preg_replace Strip Dashes from Alpha Characters (Preserve between Numbers)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I remove all dashes between Letters, but preserve any dashes in between Numbers? Sorry I don't have any previous attempts to display, because I haven't been able to find anything for this after an hour of googling. Currently I'm using a simple str_replace to remove unwanted characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookheads for this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\D)-(?=\D)/', '', 'abc-xyz-12-45-89');
//=> abcxyz-12-45-89
```

Comment: That seems to be the opposite of what I want, but it's a good start. I would change the \d to something for Alpha, right? I want to keep the dashes between numbers, and strip between letters.

Comment: Awesome. Trying now. Thanks!

Comment: For a very good reference to lookarounds: www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

If you just are interested in Letter-Letter, this might work
If you use anything other than `[a-zA-z]` or `\pL`, you will be removing
the dash between letters, punctuation, whitespace, control chars, or any combination,  etc...

Find:  `(?i)(?<=[a-z])-(?=[a-z])`
Replace with empty string.

Comment: Thanks, this is nice. Yeah, I actually do want to remove the dash EVERYWHERE except for between numbers, but this is really helpful too. I'll be coming back to reference it. Thanks much.

Comment: Ok, I wish people would state that very important detail.

Comment: Well, I did as soon as it occurred to me. So thanks.